# CSS receipt wordwrap on product

Tags: css

Whit this Code, I generate a CSS/HTML Receipt. But I have problem with long productnames

```css
.boxReceipt {
  width:300px;
}
 ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.receiptList > li {
  padding: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.receiptList > li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, 1);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.receiptList > li > .receiptPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxReceipt">
  <ul class="receiptList">
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Product 1</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Veryver very very very long product 2</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Product 3</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On a long desription I need a wordWrap. How can I make it witheout fix width?
At this moment, the prouct name is in the price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `<span class="receiptName">` and the `<span class="receiptPrice">` **float:left**, which will cause them to sit side-by-side without having to mess with their position rules.

To do this, first change the **position:absolute** to  **position:relative** in the css selecting the **receiptPrice** elements

```
.receiptList > li > .receiptPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute; <--- change to -> position:relative;
```

This will cause the span to not remove itself positionally from the rules of the parent.

Then define the widths of the spans

```
.receiptName {
  width:66%;
}

.receiptPrice {
  width:33%;
}
```

and then add the clearfix to the li elements, which will cause the overflow to work correctly

```
.receiptList > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="boxReceipt">
  <ul class="receiptList">
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Product 1</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Veryver very very very long product 2</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="receiptName">Product 3</span>
      <span class="receiptPrice">USD 124.90</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.boxReceipt {
  width:300px;
}
 ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.receiptList > li {
  padding: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.receiptList > li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, 1);
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.receiptList > li > .receiptPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
.receiptName, .receiptPrice {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}

.receiptName {
  width:66%;
}

.receiptPrice {
  width:33%;
}

.receiptList > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhabd5jf/1/